# Operating system cannot be found, Cannot boot from any device

Tags: boot, boot-loader, puppy-linux

Before this problem I was stuck in a grub rescue screen after trying to install puppy linux, and to fix it I used a boot rescue disc, but after using the boot rescue disc I restarted my computer and it says no operating system found, then this screen appears https://ibb.co/iAHe86 and I have no idea what to do from here. I thought the boot repair disc erased puppy linux after I installed it, so I put in a lubuntu disc and tried installing that, but while I was trying to install it, it said puppy linux was still on my computer, but I don't know how because its not booting. Does anyone know how I can get puppy linux to boot from here?

Comment: I solved it. I had to install grub4boot and now puppy linux boots with no issue

Answer (score 0):

Probably the PC has a working Puppy Linux partition, but `grub` somehow misconfigured itself.  The usual fix is to use a BootCD to login to a terminal, do a `chroot` to the Puppy partition, then reinstall the `grub` boot sector.

For more details, see [What's the proper way to prepare chroot to recover a broken Linux installation?](https://superuser.com/a/111215/582419) and [How to reinstall GRUB2 EFI?](https://superuser.com/q/376470/582419)

Comment: Trying this now with this http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/disk-partitioning/Repairing-a-damaged-Grub/ and using their cd.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/how-do-i-fix-a-computer-that-says-operating-system-not-found-when-booting/

please review this link. i guess you might find the answer.

Comment: this only shows you how to fix it in windows, says nothing about linux

Answer (score 0):

If computer has two or more hard drives it occasionally happens that in bios / uefi the boot drive gets misconfigured (eg during installation you unplugged drives, or something else). I had this a couple of times in the past and revising boot devices and their order in bios helped.

Comment: I think I only have one hard drive but I'm not sure.  How did you change the boot devices and order in bios?

Comment: in bios - either traditional or UEFI there is a "Boot" section giving "boot device priority" you move up or down among all your possible devices. Most bios also have a key to change boot order for this specific session (e.g. often it is F12) - so you can pick each boo device that the machine can see.